# Android Studio "Function invocation 'Button(...) expected"

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I am a novice at android studio and I am trying to make a simple calculator that takes a string and returns a value.
The issue is that when writing the code to initialize a "Button" object, it believes I am trying to call a function. It shows an error that says that:

```
Function invocation 'Button(...) expected
```

But I am not trying to call a function for button just make a Button object.

This is my main activity file:

```
package com.example.myfirstcalc

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;



class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        Button calcBtn =  (Button) findViewById(R.id.calculateBtn);
    }
}
```

This is the activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/expressionEditText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="124dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Enter an expression"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/calculateBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Calculate"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/expressionEditText"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.089" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Result"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/calculateBtn"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.124" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Wait, I believe my main activity file is currently a koltin file and not a java file and maybe thats the issue.

Comment: Yes that would cause this issue - I assumed it was Java because of the syntax

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is due to incorrect syntax. You are mixing the syntax of `Java` and `Kotlin`

To write it correctly in `Kotlin`, change the line:

```
Button calcBtn =  (Button) findViewById(R.id.calculateBtn);
```

to:

```
val calcBtn =  findViewById(R.id.calculateBtn) as Button
```

To know [basic information about Android applications in `Kotlin` see here](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/get-started.html#kotlin). To learn the basic syntax of `Kotlin`, [visit here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-syntax.html).

Comment: Give this man a raise! 

Answer (score 1):

In Kotlin you can also do:

`val calcBtn = findViewById<Button>(R.id.calculateBtn)`